# QPaint not drawing anything

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I have the most basic of Qt programs - a main window. I want to be able to use QPainter to draw some lines - nothing more than lines really (I'm trying to plot a histogram). Anyway I've read code examples but for some reason my code isn't working.

I have a **mainwindow.ui** which creates a class called **MainWindow** which I haven't shown - it's just a **QMainWindow** with a **QWidget** on it but I'm hiding the **QWidget** as I haven't used it now. **main.cc** is not shown too because it's the standard **main.cc** for a small project. The rest of the code is:

**mainwindow.cc**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
    drawingArea->hide();

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.begin(this);
    QColor color (100, 100, 100);
    painter.setBrush(color);
    painter.drawLine(0,0,10,10);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, private Ui::MainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do painting in paintEvent.

see: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/widgets-analogclock.html